# Can we get the search query that led google to our website in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Google is now using # before q. So we cannot get the search query using the referrer url.

Comment: `document.referrer`?

Comment: @Tushar - I've tried that, and it just returns `"https://www.google.com.au/"`.

Comment: Previously we could use that but now it doesn't contain the search query.

Comment: There's already an answer for that on webmaster SE, which is a better place for this type of question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59794/how-to-get-keywords-from-google-http-referrer

Comment: @Rajesh location only works on the current url right?